# Unity3D Models are pink

Tags: unity-game-engine, modeling, game-development

I have been following along a tutorial and I don't know why these prefabs appear to be pink while it should be rendered[image]. While opening the project I got an alert that my Unity version was lesser than the project's, is that the problem ? Any Suggestions would be great. Thank you!!

Comment: https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/lesson-3-1-assembling-the-set?uv=2019.4&courseId=5ee00851edbc2a0022274f75&projectId=5ed981dbedbc2a03f97c0646#5ed96cfbedbc2a115bab238c

Comment: you simply **forgot the textures**

Comment: @Fattie don't know really what happened there but upgrading the Unity Version to 2019 solved my problem finally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this problem is because the objects materials are not defined (maybe not exist, damaged... many reasons) or they are not compatible (especially their types) after you changed the unity version or the rendering pipeline.

> to solve this just assign again the materials to your objects. also in the tutorial they are giving you a link to download the materials, download them if you still didn't and assign them.

in case it was because you changed the rendering pipeline, you can update the materials under **Edit --> your rendering pipeline settings** (it is not your case but for other people who may fall in this after they had changed the rendering pipeline)

Comment: well I tried lot of things and it didn't work. Ultimately upgrading to Unity 2019 solved my problem and the prefabs render fine now. Thank you anyway!!

Answer (score 0):

It is not a big problem. You could create new Materials and assign them to your objects. Make sure the Textures are also attached to your Objects.

Comment: Yes there are no problems while developing  new game objects. The problem exists while importing pre built ones.

Comment: Thats what i meant. Just replace the materials

Comment: The game objects I am trying to import are complex and recreating will take some sweat off , also considering my current skill level.

Comment: materials were there and not showing up but upgrading the unity version to 2019 solve my Issues. Thank you!!